# TypeError while getting data to dynamically from json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
var testjson = [{"Student-Records":[{"Name":"John",}]}]

var sturec= names[k];

//    where names[k] is Student-Records
/* Proc 1 */  var temporaryjsondata = testjson [0][sturec];
/* Proc 2 */  var temporaryjsondata = testjson [0]["'"+sturec+"'"];
/* Proc 3 * Static data */ var temporaryjsondata = testjson [0]['Student-Records'];

alert(JSON.stringify(temporaryjsondata));
```

While proc 3 is static but works fine with no errors but I need to filter it by dynamic values such as `sturec` .Following `proc 1 and 2` gives alert with proper data but then give below error:

In Mozilla:

```
TypeError: temporaryjsondata is undefined
```

In chrome:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

Can anyone let me know if there is any error in above approach and how to get data dynamically. Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1kzwv331/). While the example above works perfectly fine in fiddle but fails in my application code. What are the things that may lead to this above error.

Comment: `While the example above works perfectly fine in fiddle but fails in my application code` - then you need to be looking at your other code, not this surely??

Comment: Have you tried remove space bewteen `testjson` and `[0]`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe jsFiddle is more forgiving than your strict client?

```
var testjson = [{"Student-Records":[{"Name":"John",}]}]
```

There is a comma after "John" which does not make any sense.

```
var sturec= names[k];
```

-  "names" is nowhere defined - just as "k".

```
//    where names[k] is Student-Records
/* Proc 1 */  var temporaryjsondata = testjson [0][sturec];
/* Proc 2 */  var temporaryjsondata = testjson [0]["'"+sturec+"'"];
/* Proc 3 * Static data */ var temporaryjsondata = testjson [0]['Student-Records'];
```

- "sturec" is nowhere (respectively falsely) defined.
- Please remove space between `testjson` and `[0]`.
- `["'"+sturec+"'"]` doesn't make any sense. Either sturec already contains string or else (in case it contains numbers but is needed definitely as string whyever) use `[""+sturec]`.

Please provide the actual code so we may be able to help you further.

And since you seemingly provided only partials of a more complex code and the error messages do not really fit your provided code: are you sure your alert tries to get `temporaryjsondata` while it's still in scope?